# Different node sizes conflict in TikZ tree

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing, tikz-trees

For the given tree set in TikZ I have the issue that nodes with different heights (here one line vs. two lines ) are conflicting with the separation distance. Here is the graphic which shows the problem:

[image: Tree without clean distances between one-line and two line node]

```
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=gray, anchor=west]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and %
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.5)},%
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)%
  |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
    \node {root}    
    child { 
        node {A} 
        child { 
            node {One line} 
        } 
        child { 
            node {One line} 
        } 
        child { 
            node[text width = 25em] {Two\\lines} 
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is simple with package `forest`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={grow'=0,folder,draw, align=left}
    [root
      [A
        [one line]
        [one line]
        [two\\ lines,text width=25ex]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

it define distance between nodes' edges. in example above are used default values.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If there is no following `child` after your two line child, you can safely change the `grow via three points` key for that one child:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=gray, anchor=west]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and %
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.5)},%
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)%
  |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
    \node {root}    
    child { 
        node {A} 
        child { 
            node {One line} 
        } 
        child { 
            node {One line} 
        } 
        child[grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and two children at
          (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.6)}] { 
          node[text width = 25em] {Two\\lines} 
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a nice manual solution. I fear that the "automatic" version is way too complicated, right?

Comment: @MichaelDorner one would have to check the size of the node and position it accordingly. Nothing I can do right now and I don't think am going to implement. But you can hope for one of those Ti*k*Z gurus on this page.

Comment: Oh please do not feel forced to implement for me, it was just an effort question. :) Thank you!