# organisation chart with latex

Tags: forest, organisation

[Third Level Organizational Chart using Latex Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271170/third-level-organizational-chart-using-latex-tikz?rq=1)

[image]

adding branches directly under the Controller to set up his secretariat and certain  resposibilities directly under him--how do i do it??

Comment: For starting point see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419055/

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so-far? I'm voting to close this as too broad and a -1.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Confirmed. Please extend my greetings to Erwin.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Meow!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always add some Ti*k*Z commands to add features to the tree. In this case this is the `\draw` command at the very end. I also gave the root node a name using `alias`. To generate more space, you need to nudge the tree a bit by adjusting the `fork sep` and adding some `yshift`, say.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\forestset{
  direction switch/.style={
    for tree={edge+=thick, font=\sffamily},
    where level>=1{folder, grow'=0}{for children=forked edge},
    where level=3{}{draw},
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  % forest preamble: determine layout and format of tree
  direction switch,
  for tree={fork sep=3em}
  [Life Prediction Approaches and Techniques,yshift=3em,alias=LP
    [Model-base
      [Physics-of-Failure
      ]
      [Satistical Model
        [Proportion Hazard Model]
        [Logistics Regression Model]
        [Cumulative Damage Model]
      ]
      [Kalman/Particle Filtering
      ]
      [Nonlinear Dynamics
      ]
    ]
    [Knowledge-base
      [Expert Systems
        [Rule-Based]
        [Model-Based]
        [Case-Based]
      ]
      [Fuzzy Logics
      ]
    ]
    [Experience-base
      [Parametric Distribution
        [Location Scale \& Log-Location Scale]
        [Normal \& Lognormal]
        [Smallest \& Largest Extreme Values]
        [Something Beginning with W]
        [Logistic \& Log-Logistic]
      ]
      [Nonparametric Distribution
      ]
    ]
    [Data-driven
      [Multivariate Statistical Method
        [Principal Component Analysis]
        [Something \& Something Else]
        [Another Thing]
        [A Final Thing Here]
      ]
      [Black-Box Methods
        [Decision Trees]
        [Multilayer Perceptions]
        [Neural Networks]
        [Radial Basis Functions]
        [Vector Quantification]
      ]
      [Signal Analysis
        [Auto-Something Here]
        [Fourier Transform]
        [Filters]
        [Tidal Functions]
      ]
      [Graphical Model
        [Bayesian Network]
        [Hidden Markov Networks]
      ]
      [Self-Organising Feature Maps
      ]
    ]
  ]
\draw[thick]
([yshift=-1.5em]LP.south)  -- ++(-6em,0) node[left,draw,font=\sffamily,thin]{ABC}
([yshift=-1.5em]LP.south)  -- ++(6em,0) node[right,draw,font=\sffamily,thin]{XYZ};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLDER ANSWER**: This is as simple as adding a level and shifting the numbers in the `where` clauses by 1.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271349/ addaswyd o gwestiwn OOzy Pal: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271170/
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271349/194703
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\forestset{
  direction switch/.style={
    for tree={edge+=thick, font=\sffamily},
    where level>=2{folder, grow'=0}{for children=forked edge},
    where level=4{}{draw},
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  % forest preamble: determine layout and format of tree
  direction switch,
  [Life Prediction Approaches and Techniques
   [ABC
    [Model-base
      [Physics-of-Failure
      ]
      [Satistical Model
        [Proportion Hazard Model]
        [Logistics Regression Model]
        [Cumulative Damage Model]
      ]
      [Kalman/Particle Filtering
      ]
      [Nonlinear Dynamics
      ]
    ]
    [Knowledge-base
      [Expert Systems
        [Rule-Based]
        [Model-Based]
        [Case-Based]
      ]
      [Fuzzy Logics
      ]
    ]
   ]
  [XYZ  
    [Experience-base
      [Parametric Distribution
        [Location Scale \& Log-Location Scale]
        [Normal \& Lognormal]
        [Smallest \& Largest Extreme Values]
        [Something Beginning with W]
        [Logistic \& Log-Logistic]
      ]
      [Nonparametric Distribution
      ]
    ]
    [Data-driven
      [Multivariate Statistical Method
        [Principal Component Analysis]
        [Something \& Something Else]
        [Another Thing]
        [A Final Thing Here]
      ]
      [Black-Box Methods
        [Decision Trees]
        [Multilayer Perceptions]
        [Neural Networks]
        [Radial Basis Functions]
        [Vector Quantification]
      ]
      [Signal Analysis
        [Auto-Something Here]
        [Fourier Transform]
        [Filters]
        [Tidal Functions]
      ]
      [Graphical Model
        [Bayesian Network]
        [Hidden Markov Networks]
      ]
      [Self-Organising Feature Maps
      ]
    ]
   ]    
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the cell ABC and XYZ not to be attached to any down side--they are independent

Comment: @jsbibra I added something along those lines.