# Tree is not growing the right and down in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanted my tree to grow right. Then only for this node grow down the child nodes. Unfortunately they are growing down but the levels are growing left. Why the tree is going down like this?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]


\begin{tikzpicture}
[edge from parent/.style= {thick, draw= cyan, edge from parent fork right},
gg/.style={grow=down},
 %color and box
 1/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=cyan!95, rounded corners=.8ex},
 2/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=cyan!40, rounded corners=.8ex},
 3/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=cyan!20, rounded corners=.8ex},
 %distance
 first/.style={level distance=4.5cm, align=center},
 second/.style={sibling distance=8cm,align=center},
 third/.style={sibling distance=2cm,align=center},
 fourth/.style={sibling distance=2cm,align=center},
 fifth/.style={level distance=4cm, align=center},
 sixth/.style={level distance=7ex, align=center},]

\node [1] {gg} [grow=right]
child [first,second] {node[2] {gg}
 child [third]{node[3] {child}}
 child [third]{node[3] {child}}
 child [third]{node[3] {child}}
 child [third]{node[3] {child}}
 child [third]{node[3] {child}}}
child [first,second] {node[2] {gg}
 child [third]{node[3] {child}}
 child [third]{node[3] {child}}
 child [third]{node[3] {child}}
 child [third]{node[3] {child}}}
child [first,second] {node[2] {gg}
 child [third]{node[3] {gg}}
 child [third]{node[3] {gg}}
 child [third]{node[3] {gg}
  child [gg]{node[3] {child}}
  child [gg,sixth]{node[3] {child}}
 }}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

What came out?
[image: What came out.]

What I wanted.
[image: How I want it to be]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419055/different-node-sizes-conflict-in-tikz-tree/419083#419083